# Make Google Apps site publicly accessible while disabling crawlers with robots.txt?

Tags: g-suite, access-control-list, robots.txt

I would like to **create a publicly accessible Google Apps site** (i.e. users do not need to be authenticated to access the content) while maintaining **a policy crawlers and bots exclusion with Robots.txt**. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: I don't specifically know much about Google Apps - is it stopping you from simply serving out a robots.txt "as usual"?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve as you cant make your apps site publicly accessible.

Comment: seanl, it's very possible to make a google site publicly accessible, see http://sites.google.com/a/lokad.com/translate/

Answer (score 1):

robots.txt doesn't prevent interactive browsers from using the site. It is only used by robots like crawlers, feedreaders, recursive download tools (though the latter will let the user override it).

Comment: Absolutely, but it does not matter in my case. I just want the results not to show up in Google.

Comment: Yeah, but now it's obvious you can just write a two-line robots.txt that excludes everyone everywhere (/ and *).